# Image Itertaion is slow

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have list of images and a template and need to compare template matches to which image. I have implemented multiprocessing too, it has fasten the programs but if the size of list is large it is taking many  seconds to yield the results. how can I fasten the program to yield result in ns even if the list size is larger.

```
def compare_images(original, image_to_compare):
    (score, diff) = ssim(original, image_to_compare, full=True)
    diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")
    score= score*100
    print("SSIM: {}".format(score))
    
    if(score > 90):
        return True
    else:
        return False



f = partial(compare_images, template)
with Pool() as p:
    result= p.map(f, converted_screens)
    print(result)
```

where template is the image that I have to find and converted_screens is the list to which I am doing comparsion and both are the global variables and are converted to gray color space using cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY).

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a list of things to think about.

First of all, what packages are you using for function `ssim()`. That's the first thing I would see if there is a faster competition on the market.
*e.g. If you only need photos which resemble your template in 90%, the checker should stop its work and return `False` immediately when it becomes impossible, aka there is more then 10% difference.*

Second of all, you can look at [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/10x-faster-parallel-python-without-python-multiprocessing-e5017c93cce1) about `Ray`, which is supposedly much faster than `multiprocessing`.

An additional thought, if you really care about even small gains in speed, printing to console takes quite some time, when done each iteration. If you don't need all results, consider returning only the best 90% or so.